# Read huge csv file using `read.csv` by divide-and-conquer strategy?

Tags: r, csv, memory, fread, read.csv

I am supposed to read a big csv file (5.4GB with 7m lines and 205 columns) in R. I have successfully read it by using `data.table::fread()`. But I want to know is it possible to read it by using the basic `read.csv()`?

I tried just using brute force but my 16GB RAM cannot hold that. Then I tried to use the 'divide-and-conquer' (chunking) strategy as below, but it still didn't work. How should I do this?

```r
dt1 <- read.csv('./ss13hus.csv', header = FALSE, nrows = 721900, skip =1)
print(paste(1, 'th chunk completed'))
system.time(
  for (i in (1:9)){
    tmp = read.csv('./ss13hus.csv', header = FALSE, nrows = 721900, skip = i * 721900 + 1)
    dt1 <- rbind(dt1, tmp)
    print(paste(i + 1, 'th chunk completed'))
  }
)
```

Also I want to know how `fread()` works that could read all the data at once and very efficiently no matter in terms of memeory or time?

Comment: I don't think the problem is *loading* the data, it's *holding* the data, my guess. Not to mention that an iterative build with `rbind` is always a bad thing: each time it adds *anything*, R makes a complete copy of the previous data. FOr previous builds, I much prefer `do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(fnames, read.csv))`, but I don't know that that's going to fix your large-data problem. If that doesn't work, you might consider processing only a portion of the data at a time, aggregate it (?), save it, and move on to the next batch.

Comment: Yes it's called reading in chunks. **Your issue however is with the memory bloat caused from not defining colClasses for your 205 columns** (do you really need to read all of them? it'll be a very tight fit)

Comment: Yes, I need to read all the data. But how can I get rid of the memory issue?

Comment: **Define colClasses for your 205 columns**, integers for integer columns, numeric for double columns, factors for factor columns. Otherwise things get stored very inefficiently. Please see `?fread` and the manual.

Answer (score 4):

**Your issue is not `fread()`, it's the memory bloat caused from not defining colClasses for all your (205) columns**. But be aware that trying to read all 5.4GB into 16GB RAM is really pushing it in the first place, you almost surely won't be able to hold all that dataset in-memory; and even if you could, you'll blow out memory whenever you try to process it. So your approach is not going to fly, you seriously have to **decide which subset you can handle - which fields you absolutely need to get started**:

- **Define colClasses for your 205 columns**: 'integer' for integer columns, 'numeric' for double columns, 'logical' for boolean columns, 'factor' for factor columns. Otherwise things get stored very inefficiently (e.g. millions of strings are very wasteful), and the result can easily be 5-100x larger than the raw file.
- If you can't fit all 7m rows x 205 columns, (which you almost surely can't), then **you'll need to aggressively reduce memory by doing some or all of the following**:

  - **read in and process chunks** (of rows) (use `skip, nrows` arguments, and search SO for questions on fread in chunks)
  - **filter out all unneeded rows** (e.g. you may be able to do some crude processing to form a row-index of the subset rows you care about, and import that much smaller set later)
  - **drop all unneeded columns** (use fread `select`/`drop` arguments (specify vectors of column names to keep or drop).
- Make sure **option `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`**, it's a notoriously bad default in R which causes no end of memory grief.
- **Date/datetime fields are currently read as character** (which is bad news for memory usage, millions of unique strings). Either totally drop date columns for beginning, or read the data in chunks and convert them with the `fasttime` package or standard base functions.
- Look at the args for NA treatment. You might want to drop columns with lots of NAs, or messy unprocessed string fields, for now.

Please see `?fread` and the [`data.table` doc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.2/topics/fread) for syntax for the above. If you encounter a specific error, post a snippet of say 2 lines of data (`head(data)`), your code and the error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!But it seems you misunderstood my question.I have already successfully loaded this 5.4GB file by using fread()(And there is more than 30% more free memory), but didn't work for R baisc function 'read.csv'

Comment: My current wonder is that possible just using the basic 'read.csv()' to load the whole data? It should be OK right?Because fread() has already successfully loaded.

Comment: You can also write code around `read.csv()` to read files in chunks (use `nrows`, `skip` parameters). `read.csv` also takes `colClasses` argument and that helps you reduce memory usage. I guess given `fread()` works, you're just curious to debug why `read.csv` chokes. Try `read.csv(..., nrows=1000)`, then see what columns are blowing uop your memory usage. But honestly, basic `read.csv()` is known to have bad performance on large files, so I wouldn't spend much time on it, this is the whole reason why users wrote `data.table::fread()` and `readr` packages which are way better.

Comment: @HengchengZhu: I can't see much point investigating why `read.csv`'s performance is so awful (runtime and memory). Almost all of the tips I gave you are also true for `read.csv`. If you want to you can dig into it and post your findings. `read.csv` is known to have awful performance, hence people wrote better implementations `data.table::fread()`, `readr` package etc.